# Multilevel dropdown with checkboxes in Select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create nested dropdowns with each having checkboxes in like this:
I am attaching the photo

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7jBc.png)

Is there a way to do this in react. Couldn't find a way to implement this with any specific library

I have searched on different forums didn't find any similar component implemented

Comment: You can use `rc-tree` library for this.